# How can I handle a NULLable Int column returned from a stored procedure in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns two int Values.  The first can not be null but the second can actually return a null value.  When I try to execute my stored procedure using LINQ to SQL it fails with the statement:

> The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type.

I tried to change my designer file in my DBML and add in:  `CanBeNull= true`  to the Column mapping of the Stored Procedures Result.

I'm can seem to figure out the correct way to handle this, not sure if I can change my LINQ/C# code to account for the null (which would be preferable) or if I will have to update my Stored Procedure in some fashion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to declare the variable to be nullable. In the designer, click the property in your model that needs to be nullable, and then in the **Properties** window, set the "Nullable" property to **True**. This will tell the generator to create your property as `Nullable<int> or int?`

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring the int variables as nullable.  I.e.

```
int? myInt;
```

This way you can check them for null.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error, The reason was that i have changed a field to allow null in table but i have not dropped that table in .dbml file. This issue is solved by deleting and  again dropping that table in .dbml file.

Hope this will help for some other users.

Thanks.